# Is there a way to create a jrebel plugin to hot deploy xml files (mule flows) in mule 3.6.2?

Tags: xml, mule, jrebel

I'd like to know if there is a way to create a special plugin o library in order to let JRebel hot deploy mule flows (xml files) in mule 3.6.2. We could hot deploy java classes and libraries in mule by using JRebel. However, changes made to mule flows, xml files, were not hot deployed.

Comment: I don't think Mule and JRebel will play well together Mule is not officially supported by JRebel

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tryed myself, but out of my understanding of JRebel and given the fact that a Mule XML is actually a Spring XML. I would give it a try to the Spring plugin for JRebel.

Answer (score 1):

JRebel should read all the files from your workspace with correct rebel.xml mappings, which means the XML files also get updated. If the change does not reflect in the application then most likely the issue is somewhere in the logic what loads and processes those XML files during startup. You can request the feature from support@zeroturnaround.com and are more likely to get it working if you provide a sample app that reproduces the issue.